# How to display NSDictionary key and values in UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have the `NSDictionary` like this:-

```
aberrancy =     (
    "0Dilution for Infusion.html"
);
accessory =     (
    "0Dilution for Infusion.html"
);
activity =     (
    "0Pharmacology.html"
);
acute =     (
    "0Pharmacology.html"
);
adenosine =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
administration =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
aneurysm =     (
    "0Dilution for Infusion.html"
);
arrhythmias =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
artery =     (
    "0Dilution for Infusion.html"
);
asthma =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
```

i want to show these key with its values in the `textlabel` and `detailtextLabel` of  `UITableView`.
please tell me how to do that i am new to ios programming.

Comment: Have done any homework on your behalf?

Comment: Did you try anything? Stack overflow is for giving solution to your problems. not to write full answers and codes for you

Comment: This solves my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281629/nsarraym-isequaltostring-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x8d70f00

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code to create a dictionary and then extract the keys and values separately in two different arrays.

```
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"1",@"2",@"2", nil];
  NSArray *keyArray = [dictionary allKeys];
  NSArray *valueArray = [dictionary allValues];
```

Here is a sample TableView datasource methods. This is how you should read the values.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [keyArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];

  [cell.textLabel setText:[keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

  return cell;
}
```