# _NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d70f00

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

i have NSDictionary with with key and its value and i want it to populate into the tableview but i get some error like this:

```
  -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f8e4d0
2014-08-13 13:29:45.357 SotaApp[1602:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f8e4d0'
```

what i have tried is:

```
NSString *value = [filteredDictionaryValues valueForKey:[filteredDictionaryValues.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

cell.textLabel.text =[filteredDictionaryValues.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = value;
```

Please tell me whats the problem,
thank you.

**EDIT**
the dictionary looks like this:

```
activity =     (
    "0Pharmacology.html"
);
acute =     (
    "0Pharmacology.html"
);
adenosine =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
administration =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
aneurysm =     (
    "0Dilution for Infusion.html"
);
arrhythmias =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
artery =     (
    "0Dilution for Infusion.html"
);
asthma =     (
    "0Guidelines Precautions.html"
);
atrium =     (
    "0Dosing.html"
);
```

I have filtered the dictionary from search method:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

{

```
if (searchText.length == 0) {
    isSearching = NO;
}
else{
    isSearching = YES;
}





 NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self beginswith[c]    %@",searchText];

NSArray *filteredKeys =[[myDictionary allKeys]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"filtered keys are %@",filteredKeys);

filteredDictionaryValues =[myDictionary dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:filteredKeys];
NSLog(@"filteredDicValues are %@",filteredDictionaryValues);




[self.SerchTable reloadData];
```

}

Comment: Could you add how you populate your dictionary please ?

Comment: my dictionary is filteredDictionaryValues. i have added that:

Comment: The code you're showing is not creating any problem. Where in your code you've used `isEqualToString` or please check the exception logs again and trace out the line number.

Comment: @Rajeev What I was asking is could you show how did you create this dictionary and what is in it.

Comment: @Rajeev The problem is that your dictionary is mapping keys to _arrays_, each one containing a single string (which is probably not what you intended to do). So can you share some code showing how you create this dict?

Comment: i have added that now

Comment: bro, actually u r comparing nsarray with string that why u getting error@Rajeev

Comment: but how to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling `[filteredDictionaryValues valueForKey:[filteredDictionaryValues.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]`, value returned is NSArray with 1 string object (`NSArray *array = [filteredDictionaryValues valueForKey:[filteredDictionaryValues.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; NSString *string = [array firstObject];`). If you can, you should change the way dictionary is populated(instead of array with 1 object just object). If not, just use firstObject from returned array.